# PHP active section after page refresh

Tags: php, tabs

I am trying to create a one page navigation menu in PHP. The reason I want it to be in PHP is because I can add other code later and I want the user to be on the same page even after a refresh.

I have an unordered list with generated list items. The list items are generated with an array.

*(I want the key/values separated because the actual code will be different. This is just an example.)*

```
$nav = array(
       "home" => "home",
       "about" => "about",
       "contact" => "contact"
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach( $nav as $id => $name )
{
    echo '<li><a href="#'.$id.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

// outputs:
<ul>
   <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I want some divs to be the sections

```
foreach( $nav as $s_id => $s_name)
{
    echo '<div id="'.$s_id.'">Some section text</div>';
}
```

**Now I need to know how can I set the display to either block or none based on current id active?**

Comment: Well, how do you know which one is active?  When the user clicks on those links, I wouldn't expect a page refresh.  And nothing after the `#` fragment is sent to the server.  It sounds like you want to do this in JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: I do know that the page is not refreshed after a link has been clicked. I know you can do it in Javascript however if a user would then refresh the page they are redirected to the first active content, so the "#" gets removed again. I know that it's possible in php and I rather have it that way. And maybe I shouldn't use anchor href's to achieve it but I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I personally think this is more of a job for JavaScript, in the question and a comment above you specify that you want to do this in PHP.  In that case those anchor tags will need to be actual links to the page.  For the sake of this example I'll assume the page is called `index.php`.  (If it's something different, just use whatever your page is.)

Update the anchors to be links to the page with query string parameters:

```
<li><a href="index.php?active=home">home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?active=about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?active=contact">contact</a></li>
```

Then in your PHP code you'd determine which one is "active" by the `active` query string parameter.  Start with a default of `"home"` in case no parameter is specified (it's the user's first time on the page):

```
$active = "home";
if (isset($_GET["active"])) {
    $active = $_GET["active"];
}
```

Then when rendering the `<div>` elements you can specify their style:

```
foreach( $nav as $s_id => $s_name)
{
    echo '<div id="'.$s_id.'" style="display:'.($s_id == $active ? "block" : "none").'">Some section text</div>';
}
```

Comment: When I added the code you provided it gave an "Object not found" error. Is there maybe another way of doing it? Javascript would be fine if it makes sure the user is still on the same tab after they would refresh a page.

Comment: @Leonator: What specifically gives that error?  Yes, JavaScript would make sense for this functionality, but you've specifically indicated that you don't want that.

Comment: The error is for the link I clicked. I have an example code, where php was used for this task, however I cannot completely figure out how it would work. I will add it to my question later today.

Comment: I finally got it to work! I accidentally used the wrong query string before. Thank you soo much!